# How do i use apply with an array and a scalar?

Tags: r

If I have an array

```
a = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

I would like to apply the "which" function to each scalar in 1:3

```
l = list()
for(i in 1:3){
 l[[i]] = which(a == i)
}
```

how do I vectorize this operation with a apply, lapply, Map?

Comment: Are you looking for something more general or to simplify this specific example? You could provide more context or try `split(seq_along(a), a)`, respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main argument of `lapply` should be the dimension of list elements you want to end up with. Which is the what you are looping over in your `for` example, so:

```
a = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
lapply(1:3, function(x) which(a == x))
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to code `a` into the anonymous function you can use:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x, y) which(y == x), y = a)
```

Comment: the second one is what i was looking for, I dind't know how to "not apply" the function over the "a" element by element. I didn't think about additional arguments. Thank you